# Regex matching final occurrence of a pattern

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm trying to match the final occurrence of a pattern of WWNs like this:

```
addr: 10:00:00:00:c4:a2:42:15
port: 10:00:00:00:c4:a2:42:15
addr: 10:00:00:00:c4:a2:42:16
port: 10:00:00:00:c4:a2:42:16
```

When I tested this:

```
port: (([0-9a-f]{2}[:-]){7}([0-9a-f]{2}))(?!.*port: ([0-9a-f]{2}[:-]){7}([0-9a-f]{2}))
```

it matches only `10:00:00:00:c4:a2:42:15`. I thought my regex is non-greedy, but it looks like I'm still missing something.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`.` doesn't match newlines. Try using `[\s\S]` instead:

```
port: (([0-9a-f]{2}[:-]){7}([0-9a-f]{2}))(?![\s\S]*port: ([0-9a-f]{2}[:-]){7}([0-9a-f]{2}))
                                            ^^^^^^
```

[rubular demo](http://rubular.com/r/KJrS9rpDSA)

Comment: @CenterOrbit The problem with regexr is that it's a Javascript regex tester and this is a Ruby question. the two languages have some differences in regex implementation.